# Find possible boolean values to evaluate an expression to true

Tags: logic, expression, logical-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

If I have a given boolean expression (`AND` and `OR` operations) with many boolean variables, then I want to evaluate this expression to true, how can I find the set of all possible boolean values to achive a true epxression?

For example, I have 4 boolean variable `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and an expression:

```
 (a ^ b) v (c ^ d)
```

The slowest way I've tried to do is:

- I  build an expression tree to get all variables in the expression, I get a `{a,b,c,d}` set.
- I find all subsets of the set: `{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {a,b}, {a,c}, {a,d}, {b,c}, {b,d}, {c,d}, {a,b,c},  {a,b,d}, {a,c,d}, {b,c,d}, {a,b,c,d}`
- For each subset, I set each of variables to true, then evaluate the expression. If the expression returns true, I save the subset with the values.

**EDIT:** I eliminate the `NOT` operator to make the problem simpler.

Comment: I hope you know that this is an NP-complete problem.

Comment: @chris Which problem do you mean?

Comment: The one in your question. If you know all possible sets of values that produce a true expression, you know whether a solution exists, and thus you can trivially solve the [SAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem). Since that's NP-complete (and probably the most famous one), this is as well.

Comment: @chris Not quite: this shows this problem is NP-_hard_, but to be NP-complete it also needs to be in NP. And unless I am missing something it isn't: the length of the answer can be exponential, and just producing it is impossible in NP even if you didn't need to find it :)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, Ooh, good point. I didn't think much about going the other way.

Comment: @chris So that I don't end up being misleading: the actual reason it isn't in NP is that NP is a class of _decision_ problems, i.e. their answers must be yes/no by definition. I should have said it isn't in FNP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FNP_(complexity)).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, Right, I ignored the decision problem aspect in order to use more well-known terminology and make a point that the question is at least as hard as this well-known NP-complete problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see a way to compute this without having to try all the permutations, and my high level outline, described below, is not really very complicated. I'll outline the basic approach, and you will have two follow-up tasks to do on your own:

- Parsing a logical expression, like "A && (B || C)" into a classical parse tree, that represents the expression, which each node in the tree being either a variable, or a boolean operation, either "&&", "||", or "!" (NOT), with two children being its operands. This is a classical parse tree. Plenty of examples of how to do this can be found in Google.
- Translating my outline into actual C++ code. That's going to be up to you also, but I think that the implementation should be rather obvious, once you wrap your brain around the overall approach.

To solve this problem, I'll use a two-phase approach.

1. I will use the general approach of [proof by induction](https://www.google.com/search?q=proof+by+induction) in order to come up with a tentative list of all potential sets of values of all the variables for which the boolean expression will evaluate to `true`.
2. In the second phase I'll eliminate from the list of all potential sets those sets that are logically impossible. This might sound confusing, so I'll explain this second phase first.

Let's use the following datatypes. First, I'll use this datatype of possible values for which the boolean expression will evaluate to either `true` or `false`:

```
typedef std::set<std::pair<std::string, bool>> values_t;
```

Here, `std::pair<std::string, bool>` represents variable, whose name is `std::string`, has this `bool` value. For example:

```
{"a", true}
```

Means that the value of variable "a" has the value of `true`. It follows that this `std::set` represents a set of variables and their corresponding values.

All of these potential solutions are going to be an:

```
typedef std::list<values_t> all_values_t;
```

So this is how we will represent a list of all combinations of values of all variables, that produce the result of either `true` or `false`. You can use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::list`, it doesn't really matter.

Now notice that it is possible for a `values_t` to have both:

```
 {"a", true}
```

and

```
 {"a", false}
```

in the set. This means that in order for the expression to evaluate to `true` or `false`, "a" must be simultaneously true and false.

But this is, obviously, logically impossible. So, in phase 2 of this solution you will need to go simply go through all the individual `values_t` in `all_values_t`, and remove the "impossible" `values_t` that contain both `true` and `false` for the some variable. The way to do this should seem rather obvious, and I won't waste time on describing it, but phase 2 should be straightforward, once phase 1 is complete.

For phase 1 our goal is to come up with a function that's roughly declared like this:

```
all_values_t phase1(expression_t expr, bool goal);
```

`expr` is a parsed representation of your boolean expression, as a parse tree (as I mentioned in the beginning, doing this part will be up to you). `goal` is how you want the parsed expression to be evaluated to: `phase1()` returns all possible `all_values_t` for which `expr` evaluates to either `true` or `false`, as indicated by "goal". You will, obviously, call `phase1()` passing `true` for "goal" for your answer, because that's what you want to figure out. But `phase1()` will call itself recursively, with either a `true` or a `false` "goal", to do its magic.

Before proceeding, it is important now to read and understand the various resources that describe how a proof by induction works. Don't proceed any further until you understand this general concept fully.

Ok, now you understand the concept. If you do, then you must now agree with me that `phase1()` is already done. It works! Proof by induction starts by assuming that `phase1()` does what it is supposed to do. `phase1()` will make recursive calls to itself, and since `phase1()` returns the right result, `phase1()` can simply rely on itself to figure everything out. See how easy this is?

`phase1()` really has one "simple" task at hand:

- Check what the top level node of the parse tree is. It will be either a variable node or an expression node (see above).
- Return the appropriate `all_values_t`, based on that.

That's it. We'll take both possibilities, one at a time.

1. The top level node is a variable.

So, if your expression is just a variable, and you want the expression to return `goal`, then:

```
values_t v{ {name, goal} };
```

There's only one possible way for the expression to evaluate to `goal`: an obvious no-brainer: the variable, and `goal` for its value.

And there's only one possible solution. No other alternatives:

```
all_values_t res;

res.push_back(v);

return res;
```

Now, the other possibility is that the top-level node in the expression is one of the boolean operations: and, or, or not.

Again, we'll divide and conquer this, and tackle each one, one at a time.

Let's say that it's "not". What should we do then? That should be easy:

```
return phase1(child1, !goal);
```

Just call `phase1()` recursively, passing the "not" expression's child node, with `goal` logically inverted. So, if your `goal` was true, use `phase1()` to come back with what the values for "not" sub-expression being false, and vice-versa. Remember, proof by induction assumes that `phase1()` works as advertised, so you can rely on it to get the correct answer for the sub-expression.

It should now start becoming obvious how the rest of `phase1()` works. There are only two possibilities left: the "and" and the "or" logical operation.

For the "and" operation, we'll consider, separately, whether the "goal" of the "and" operation should be `true` or `false`.

If `goal` is true, you must use `phase1()` to come up with `all_values_t` for both subexpressions being true:

```
all_values_t left_result=phase1(child1, true);

all_values_t right_result=phase1(child2, true);
```

Then just combine the two results together. Now, recall that `all_values_t` is a list of all ***possible*** values. Each value in `all_values_t` (which can be an empty list/vector) represents one possible solution. Both the left and the right sub-expressions must be logically combined, but any possible solution from the `left_result` can go together with any `right_result`. Any potential solution with the left subexpression being true can (and must) go with any potential solution with the right subexpression being true.

So the `all_values_t` that needs to be returned, in this case, is obtained by doing a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) between the `left_result` and the `right_result`. That is: taking the first value, the first `values_t` `std::set` in the `left_result`, then adding to this set the first `right_result` `std::set`, then the first `left_result` with the second `right_result`, and so on; then the second `left_result` with the first `right_result`, then the second `right_result` and so on. Each one of these combinations gets `push_back()`ed into the `all_values_t` that gets returned from this call to `phase1`().

But your `goal` is to have the "and" expression return `false`, instead, you simply have to do a variation of this three times. The first time by calling `phase1(child1, false)` with `phase1(child2, false)`; then `phase1(child1, true)` with `phase1(child2, false)`; and finally `phase1(child1, false)` and `phase1(child2, true)`. Either `child1` or `child2`, or both, must evaluate to `false`.

So that takes care of the "and" operation.

The last, and the final possibility for `phase1()` to deal with is the logical or operation. You should be able to, now, figure out how to do it by yourself, but I'll just briefly summarize it:

If `goal` is false, you must call `phase1(child1, false)` with `phase1(child2, false)`, then combine both results together, as a cartesian product. If `goal` is true, you will make three sets of recursive calls, for the three other possibilities, and combine everything together.

You're done. There's nothing else for `phase1()` to do, and we completed our proof by induction.

Well, I lied a little bit. You'll also need to do a small "Phase 3". Recall that in "Phase 2" we eliminated all impossible solution. Well, it is possible that, as a result of all this, the final list of possible solution will have the same `values_t` occur more than one time in the `all_values_t`, so you'll just have to dedupe it.

P.S. It's also possible to avoid a discrete phase 2 by doing it on the fly, as part of phase 1. This variation is going to be your homework assignment, too.